# Having trouble understanding the relationship between convergence order and convergence rate

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I'm in a Numerical Analysis course and we're learning about root finding.  I'm looking at the definition $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-x^*|}{|x_n-x^*|^p}=C$$
Where $x^*$ is the limit of $x_n$, $x_n\neq x^*$ and $C$ is the rate of convergence, or asymptotic error constant.  I've learned in class that the smaller the $C$ the faster it converges as well.

So suppose we have a sequence $x_k$ that converges to $x^*$ at order $p$ with asymptotic error constant $C>0$. Why would changing the exponent on the denominator, say $q$, as in [this document](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/convergence), change the rate of convergence, or $C$?

Comment: For example let $p=2$. What is the limit for $0<q<p=2$?

Comment: My only guess would be that since the denominator increases more slowly, the limit would be lower? That's essentially what I'm asking.  I want to know why decreasing the power on the denominator changes the $C$.

Comment: Yes. But You can give a definitive answer.

Comment: If you need an example, take $x_n = 2^{-2^n}$.

Comment: Okay.  In that example, $x^*=0$, and so using $p=2$ we obtain $\lim{n\to\infty}=\frac{|2^{-2^{n+1}}|}{|2^{-2^n}|^2}=1$.  But if we use $q=1<p$ the limit falls to 0.

Comment: yes. That is in general true. For smaller order, the limit is always $0$.

Comment: Is there a non-example based reason why that is true?  Why is it generally true?

Comment: $q = p - (p-q)$ and $p-q>0$. You should be able to guess what happens, if $C>0$ and $q>p$.